# error appearing in kue ui when trying to run it

Tags: node.js, titanium-alloy, kue

**This is the error in the kue ui at localhost:6379/active  in my web browser.**

```
TypeError:
E:\development\workspace\wmtservices\node_modules\kue\lib\http\views\_filter.jade:3
1| select#filter
2|   option(value='') filter by
> 3|   - each type in types
4|     option(value=type)= type

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at jade.debug.unshift.lineno (eval at <anonymous> (E:\development\workspace\wmtservices\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:166:8), <anonymous>:234:31)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (E:\development\workspace\wmtservices\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:166:8), <anonymous>:265:4)
at E:\development\workspace\wmtservices\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:167:35
at Object.exports.render (E:\development\workspace\wmtservices\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:201:14)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\development\workspace\wmtservices\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:228:13)
at View.render (E:\development\workspace\wmtservices\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:75:8)
at Function.app.render (E:\development\workspace\wmtservices\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:503:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render (E:\development\workspace\wmtservices\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:755:7)
at Command.callback (E:\development\workspace\wmtservices\node_modules\kue\lib\http\routes\index.js:23:11)
at RedisClient.flush_and_error (E:\development\workspace\wmtservices\node_modules\redis\index.js:117:25)
```

**This is the code in the js file written in titanium **

```
var kue = require('kue'),
job = kue.job,
redis = require('redis');
// creating redis client....
kue.redis.createClient = function(){
var client = redis.createClient('6379','127.0.0.1',{no_ready_check: true});
return client;
};

var jobs = kue.createQueue();
var job = jobs.create('test', {
title: 'matching twins'
}).priority('high').save();
```

*this is the ui part of the kue...*

```
// start the UI
kue.app.listen(6379);
console.log('UI started on port 6379');
```

*Even without initialising a job i am getting the same error in the kue ui...*

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order like this:

```
var kue = require('kue'),
redis = require('redis');
// creating redis client....
kue.redis.createClient = function(){
var client = redis.createClient('6379','127.0.0.1',{no_ready_check: true});
return client;
};

var job = kue.job;
```

You don't want to start kue until the Redis client is set up.

Comment: i have changed the order but still the error is persisting.The kue ui is still giving the same error.am i creating the job correctly??

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the issue now. The Kue needs to run on a different port than your Redis interface. Try `kue.app.listen(4000);` and connecting to

```
http://localhost:4000
```

Comment: when the kue and redis ports are different i am getting an Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6389 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED.Does initialising the kue ui have to be in a different js..?

Comment: They need to be different ports. 6379 is the Redis port. You need to put the Kue Express app at a different port for viewing the management interface.